# MVC3 razor create user without registering

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, razor

I have an MVC3 razor page that uses a loginview and register that works (and writes to a database that I have created).  However I would like to create users without using the register function.  Is there a way to do that using visual studio 2010

Comment: So in Visual Studio 2010 asp.net , there is a web tool you can open up to add users, does a similar one exist in razor?

Comment: @Badmiral - Razor has nothing to do with anything.  Razor is just a templating engine.  Visual Studio provides the Web Administration tool, not MVC or Webforms or razor.

Comment: Just didn't know the name, thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, does Visual Studio provide a user interface to allow you to do this?  The answer is... Maybe.

If you're using the standard SqlMembershipProvider, then yes.  There's something called the Web Site Administrator tool, which you can use to create users, roles, etc..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Web_Site_Administration_Tool

However, be aware that if you're not using the standard SqlMembershipProvider, it may not work.  This is the case with the default project templates provided by Visual Studio 2012, which use SimpleMembership rather than SqlMembership.

If you mean is there an API that let's you create users... think about it for a second.  How does your website register the users?  Look at the code.  It's the same API.

Answer (score 1):

To create users programatically (which is what I think you are asking) use your [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) provider.

```
Membership.CreateUser(... params)
```